# how to run system services by sending request via browser

Tags: linux, browser, apache-http-server, services, embedded-linux

I want to create an interface similar to that of a dsl router where you can edit network settings in the browser and restart the router with new settings. I want to edit some settings  in the browser and run a systemd service via a button or something similar. e.g  I want to submit an html form to python CGI script which would then modify the eth1.network file and restart the networkd service. I have an embedded Linux device with Apache web server running on it.

The problem is: Apache web user is not allowed to start/stop system services and of-course i don't want to allow the www-data to start/stop systemd services.

- How can i start/stop systemd services from the browser without allowing root privileges to www-data user. I know that web server should never be allowed to access services or any thing out side the root folder 'var/www/' for security reasons.
- How does a DSL router accomplishes this?
  one solution that I found is here [Is it safe to allow www-data to execute privileged commands](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/is-it-safe-to-allow-www-data-to-execute-privileged-commands) but i dont know how can i implement that. I would apreciate any guide or examples.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT allow to run privileged commands by exposed to the wild internet `www-data` user. It is a way for looking for trouble.

You can use [URL-knocking](https://superuser.com/a/1176403/164837) for such things. You can create secret URL and on the server continuously monitor for changes apache's log file with `tail -f` that doesn't load server since it used kernel's *inotify* feature. This way, when you call your secret URL, a script (whatever if it shell, python and so on) that runs under privileged account will run single, particular task. So, basically it kind of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) between unprivileged user and operations that need to be done with highest (root?) privileges. You should implement some authentication mechanism to protect that secret URL to avoid DDoS. Also, if you would use HTTPS for such things then your secret URL wouldn't be exposed to [man-in-a-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).